# How to make a part of canvas clickable?

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is make a part of the canvas clickable. And when I click it a function gets called. How do you do that in JavaScript?

Comment: Is the part that you want clickable static (is it always in the same location)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to bind a click event to the whole canvas and detect the position of the cursor on the click, and then, if the cursor is within certain dimensions, you execute the function.

Here's a fiddle, using a div as an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/R8rED/17/

```
function testAndExecute(elem, event, area, func){
    // area is relative to page :
    // var area = {
    //     x0: 60,
    //     y0: 60,
    //     x1: 100,
    //     y1: 100
    // }    
    elem.addEventListener(event, function(e){
        var page = {
            x: e.pageX,
            y: e.pageY
        }
        if(page.x >= area.x0 && page.x <= area.x1 && page.y >= area.y0 && page.y <= area.y1){
            func();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this would work for a particular screen resolution only.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to make a region of the canvas clickable, an easy way to do that would be to overlay an invisible div on top of the canvas.

CSS:

```
#clickable-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Here is an example where you can click in the top left corner of the canvas.
http://jsfiddle.net/tsanders/V6qGM/38/